# Firefox. Undo "Do this automatically for files like this from now on"

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, winrar

I have dowlnoaded RAR archive and clicked `"Do this automatically for files like this from now on"` checkbox to open in `WinRAR`. But now I'm tired of this. I want just save it.

BUT, there no RAR option in `Options > Applications`.

Where should I change it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're on Windows, go to:

`Options` -> `Applications` tab

Search `winrar`

In the results below, select

`WinRAR Archive (application rar)` -> `Always ask`

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: It was my first try, but as I`ve pointed - WinRAR options are not present here. FlashGot intercepts this calls.

Comment: I misread your question. You should tick your own answer below as it perfectly answers the question. Glad you had it figured out :)

Answer (score 0):

I've found problem. I have `FlashGot` Add-on. And `RAR` saved here, instead of `Options -> Applications` :

[image]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[image]